# How do I tell what aura my Paladin has?

Tags: airmech

I just tried out the new Paladin and noticed that it has defense, attack, and speed auras. As I understand it, right-clicking switches between the auras, but I can't tell what it's on ever. The icons are color-coded, but I don't see any matching colors anywhere else.

[image]

Is there some way to tell what aura is currently on, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Aura shows up when you hold right click while airborne, and indefinitely while you are on the ground. The CTRL key is what cycles them.

Comment: Yep, you have to push control once to start it, but then it does show([example 1](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=162983413), [example 2](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=162983352)) an aura under everyone around me. Thanks.